# how to use screen and include command line flags

Tags: python, screen, theano

I generally use

```
screen -dmSL screen_name python myfile.py
```

to run a program in screen. Theano programs requires the flags

```
THEANO_FLAGS='mode=FAST_RUN,device=cuda,floatX=float32,optimizer_including=cudnn'
```

in the front, which causes the screen command to fail.

How do you make this work

```
screen -dmSL screen_name THEANO_FLAGS='mode=FAST_RUN,device=cuda,floatX=float32,optimizer_including=cudnn' python myfile.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `env` like this:

```
screen -dmSL screen_name env THEANO_FLAGS='mode=FAST_RUN,device=cuda,floatX=float32,optimizer_including=cudnn' python myfile.py
```